# Executar bloco caso não ocorra uma exceção

Tags: java, exceção

Quero saber se tem como executar uma função, um bloco, caso **NÃO** ocorresse uma exceção no `try {..}`.

Exemplo:

```
try {
    sout("Texto na tela");
} catch(Throwable t) {
    sout("Ocorreu uma exceção");
} casoNãoOcorraUmaExceção {
    sout("Não ocorreu uma exceção");
}
```

Deu para entender o que eu quis dizer?

Comment: Pra que complicar, meu caro? A última instrução dentro do try (imediatamente anterior ao catch) somente será executada se nenhuma exceção ocorrer. Então o que você precisa é simplesmente isso: `try {
    sout("Texto na tela"); sout("Não ocorreu uma exceção");
} catch(Throwable t) {
    sout("Ocorreu uma exceção");
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei ao certo se o Java provê este recurso diretamente, em todo caso, você pode usar uma variável controladora que indicará se houve êxito no `try`, no [`finally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) (sempre será executado na saída do `try`) você verifica o estado da variável:

```
boolean naoOcorreuExcecoes = false;

try {
    // Código para executar no bloco Try
    naoOcorreuExcecoes = true;
} catch(Throwable t) {
    // Fazer algo aqui caso ocorram exceções
}finally {
    if (naoOcorreuExcecoes){
        // Fazer algo aqui caso não ocorra exceções no Try
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O `try/catch` permite desviar a sequência normal da execução do código quando uma excepção acontece. Caso não haja nenhuma excepção, a execução segue a sequência normal.

```
try {
   sout("Texto na tela");
}catch(Throwable t) {
   sout("Ocorreu uma excepção");
   //Caso não queira que o código siga após o bloco catch
   return;
}
//Continua aqui caso não haja excepção 
sout("Não houve excepção");
.....
```

Adicionalmente existe, através da declaração do bloco `finally`, a possibilidade de definir um trecho de código que será sempre executado haja ou não excepção:

```
try {
   sout("Texto na tela");
}catch(Throwable t) {
   sout("Ocorreu uma excepção");
}
finally {  
   // Este bloco sempre será executado haja ou não excepção
}
```

Portanto, e respondendo à sua pergunta, deverá utilizar o código do primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Mas, no 1º código, caso ocorra uma excessão iria, também, executar o sout("Não houve uma excepção").

Comment: Coloque um `return` no final do bloco `catch`

Comment: Tenho a leve impressão que isso não responde ao que foi dito na pergunta, **ele pergunta**: como executar um *bloco/função* caso **não ocorra exceção** no bloco `try`. No primeiro código somente **é interrompido** a sequência normal de execução com o `return`. No segundo código, no `finally`, independente se houve exceção ou não, é feito algo. O AP pergunta uma coisa e quer outra, vai entender. =)

Comment: @qmechanik A pergunta ,de facto, não expressa o que o AP pretendia. Só ficou claro quando ele comenta a minha resposta, daí eu ter editado e adicionado o `return`.  A pergunta como está feita não faz muito sentido porque não é necessário fazer nada para que o o código execute algo quando não há excepção, ele segue a sequência normal. A pergunta deveria ser qualquer coisa do género: *"Executar bloco de código* ***apenas*** *quando não ocorra uma excepção"*

Comment: Pode explicar porque mudou de ideias em relação à pergunta aceite?

Answer (score 0):

Tem como você colocar o bloco finally

```
 try {  
sout("Texto na tela");
    }  
    catch (Exception e) {  
  sout("Ocorreu uma excessão");
    }  
    finally {  
       // Faça alguma coisa aqui, esse bloco sempre será executado 


    }
```

Comment: Mas o bloco finally é executado até mesmo quando a excessão ocorre, e eu quero que o bloco só seja executado caso a excessão NÃO ocorrer.